# Why can not use lambda in jersey?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, lambda, jersey

When I use spring mvc, jersey, and lambda, some strange things happened. To describe the problem I post the code:

```
@Path("test")
@Post
public String method(@FormParam("ids") String ids){
    Arrays.stream(ids.split(",")).map(Integer::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return "";
}
```

The inject will fail and I can not run tomcat. If I delete the lambda row, everything is fine. Why?

Comment: please elaborate on the way it "fails" - compile issue? runtime issue? Exception stacktrace?

Comment: This is supposed to work. The problem is somewhere else. Post the exact result or StackTrace.